# Drag tab to new window in foxit reader

Tags: foxit-reader

When in e.g. Chrome and Firefox, I am able to drag a tab to a new window. Is there any option to enable the same functionality in Foxit PDF reader?

Comment: https://tickets.foxitsoftware.com/create.php

Did you try creating a support ticket and request for this feature. It is 2017! and they still do not have this!

Comment: I just stopped using it all together. I found this ticket/request a long time ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think so. I experimented with FR 6.0.6.0722.

I suspect that this simply isn't functionality they ever considered. All tab interfaces are not created equal. Web browsers tabs have matured a lot and browsers have switched to multi-process models, where each tab is an independent process, which lends itself to the "detachable tab" interface. Foxit runs everything in a single process, so the tabs are really just an aid for opening multiple pdf files, not an instance of the process as it is with browsers.

Comment: https://tickets.foxitsoftware.com/create.php

Did you try creating a support ticket and request for this feature. It is 2017! and they still do not have this!